# Apache Flink: How to write from Apache Kafka to Apache Cassandra with Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-flink, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I want to write data from Kafka to Cassandra with Flink. The messages in Kafka are serialized via Avro schema which is managed by a Confluent schema registry.
I have already got

- a Kafka Consumer, which can consume the Avro messages properly
- and a CassandraSink which can write data with Flink's datatype `Row`

I've already tried to use `AvroRowDeserializationSchema` (see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/AvroRowDeserializationSchema.html)) but this didn't work due to the Confluent schema registry. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any resources to deserialize `Confluent Avro` to `Row`. 
But maybe there is a completely different and easier way to achieve this simple goal (**read `Confluent Avro` and write to Cassandra table**). I would really appreciate any hint or idea.

Comment: Use `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Kafka Connect to do this? It's built for this exact use case :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt You're right, if it would be just writing Kafka Connect would be fine. But I  want to process/transform the data a little bit, so I want to use Flink.

Comment: So, what happened when you used the class I mentioned?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was aware of this class. I used it in another consumer and it worked well. But with this I got a `DataStream<$AvroClass>`.
My question here was for a class the can deserialize ConfluentAvro directly into `Row` datatype, like `AvroRowDeserializationSchema` can but for Confluent Avro. Anyway I decided to go with the Avro Schema and transfer the `Row`-DataStreams to Confluent Avro DataStreams which is very easy. My overall goal is to only use one datatype in all my DataStreams, so my transformation code can be universal (for this project). 
Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: You could always map specific Avro types to Row classes, and implement some Factory-like interface that takes those does the conversion if you really wanted to make it generic. You might also be able to use `DataStream<GenericRecord>`, assuming the records you consume always have the same field names

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, this was an option, which didn't come to my mind... It's probably the easiest solution. As far as I tested it, this approach works well.